# Merge users with same e-mail?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I recently signed up here and had expected that a previous question I posted without signing up (although giving my e-mail adress) would be merged such that it would be attributed to my account. This did not happen though, can I do this somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Our [help system](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help) directs you to https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.